# get error in sql stored procedure table type

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have this procedure and i want insert list of value into table,and i want check duplicate value and return this but i get this error

ERROR:

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertData]
    @Value insertTbl READONLY,
    @Result INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        IF (SELECT   COUNT(Id)
            FROM     @Values
            WHERE    Id IN (SELECT   Id
                            FROM     [dbo].[username])) = 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO dbo.username ( Id, NAME )
            SELECT   Id,
                     NAME
            FROM     @Values
            WHERE    Id NOT IN (SELECT   Id
                                FROM     [dbo].[username])

            SELECT   @Result = 101
        END
        ELSE
            SELECT   @Result = (
                         SELECT  Id
                         FROM    @Values
                         WHERE   Id IN (SELECT   Id
                                        FROM     [dbo].[username])
                     )
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT   ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this.

I have changed the return type to VARCHAR. That would return a CSV (e.g. 1,3,9...)

The other option is to return a result set. For this replace `SELECT     @Result =` to `INSERT INTO @Result...`

Hope this helps.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertData]
    @Value insertTbl READONLY,
    @Result VARCHAR(500) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        IF (SELECT   COUNT(Id)
            FROM     @Values
            WHERE    Id IN (SELECT   Id
                            FROM     [dbo].[username])
           ) = 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO dbo.username (Id,NAME)
            SELECT   Id,
                     NAME
            FROM     @Values
            WHERE    Id NOT IN (SELECT   Id
                                FROM     [dbo].[username])

            SELECT   @Result = 101
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT   @Result = (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(5))
                                              FROM   @Values
                                              WHERE  Id IN (SELECT   Id
                                                            FROM     [dbo].[username])
                                              ORDER BY Id FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,''))
        END
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT   ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably this line

```
SELECT @Result=(SELECT Id FROM  @Values  WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[username]))
```

return more than one row. You should change the query to return only one value as below

```
SELECT @Result=(SELECT top 1 Id FROM  @Values  WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[username]))
```

or you should change your logic. Alternative way is to use temprary table to return listo of ID. Try below solution

```
-- create temporary table before (!) creating procedure
create table #Resulttab
(
  Result int
)
go
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertData]
    @Value insertTbl READONLY,
    @Result INT OUTPUT -- in this solution I think you don't need this parameter
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        IF (SELECT   COUNT(Id)
            FROM     @Values
            WHERE    Id IN (SELECT   Id
                            FROM     [dbo].[username])) = 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO dbo.username ( Id, NAME )
            SELECT   Id,
                     NAME
            FROM     @Values
            WHERE    Id NOT IN (SELECT   Id
                                FROM     [dbo].[username])

            SELECT   @Result = 101
        END
        ELSE
            insert into #Resulttab
            SELECT  Id
            FROM    @Values
            WHERE   Id IN (SELECT   Id
                           FROM     [dbo].[username])            
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT   ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH
END
go
```

You can use it that way:

```
 -- create temporary table before run procedure 
 create table #Resulttab
 (
      Result int
 )
 -- run procedure with parameters  
 exec insertData ...  
 --after run procedure you can check list of your IDs 
 select Result from #Resulttab
```

Comment: thnak's for your answer,but i want retun all duplicate value

Comment: @user3807529 You can't because `@Result` is `int` type not an `array`

Comment: @user3807529 I added one more solution to return tamorary table with list of ID. Consider new solution please.